# K-means clustering, how to divide datas vertically?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried to use K-means clustering method to divide 3 part of my Dataframes. I used same method and codes in 2 different Dataframes. In my first dataframe, I get 3 clusters and they separated vertically which I want. But in the second one, It clustered my datas horizontally. How can fix it? I also need to separate my values vertically in my second dataframe.

The size and columns names of these Dataframes are same, but row values are different.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm6lN.jpg)
![dataframe1-vertical][1]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBNxB.jpg)
![dataframe2-horizontal(I don't want this, I need clustering like dataframe1 like above)][2]

```py
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(dataframe1)
centroidsValues = kmeans.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(dataframe1['StoreNumber'], dataframe1['SalesNumber'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(centroidsValues[:, 0], centroidsValues[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cluster vertically, **use only the y attribute** for clustering.

If you also pass the x attribute data to the algorithm it will be used. And depending how you scale your data, it may depend mostly on the x or only the y attribute have I'd they vary a lot in scale.